# Does not work object deletion

Tags: lua

Why does not it delete the object (car) when I press the button?
When choosing a car, it will spawn. And when you close the selection window, it should disappear, but it does not disappear

```
function onGuiClick (button)
if guiGridListGetSelectedItem(loli, 1) then
    veh = createVehicle (500, 1942.6214599609, -1752.1103515625, 13.3828125)
    timer = setTimer(function() local x, y, z = getElementRotation(veh) setElementRotation(veh, x, y, z+3) end, 50, 0)
    end
end
addEventHandler ("onClientGUIClick", getRootElement(), onGuiClick)

function onGuiClick (button)
if (source == Close) then   
    Enabled = false
    guiSetVisible (Windo, false )
    showCursor(false)
    setCameraTarget(roo)
    destroyElement(veh) --this does not work
    end
end
addEventHandler ("onClientGUIClick", getRootElement(), onGuiClick)ter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

`destroyElement` is not a part of Lua standard, no one can guess, what it is supposed to do. The second function (first one too) has a bunch of uninitialized variables in it: `roo`, `Windo` and especially `veh`. What happens when your framework functions receive `nil`s instead of those is anyone's guess. If you initialize them somewhere else, it is not clear from the code.

Whether the two handlers share the global space and whether it is preserved between game frames\updates (this is some game, isn't it?) depends on the framework. Probably it's a good time to open up manual on `addEventHandler`.